# TCP/IP Netbios fail; Dependant service "NetBT" not installed

Tags: services, tcpip, pppoe

I've been hit by zeroaccess virus last week, it corrupted the internet connection and dns system.

I cleaned everything and everything is working fine except pppoe connectins, they fail with Error 720

I looked into solving this issue and found out dhcp and "tcp/ip netbios" services are corrupted.

I fixed dhcp services from another computer and it's working fine.
But "tcp/ip netbios" service failed due to dependency error where it need "netbt" service to start.

I restored netbt values from another pc but when i try to run this service from command promp with:

```
net start netbt
```

i get this error message:

```
The service name is invalid.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

My system is windows 7 32bit.

Comment: How did you repair from another computer? Did you try `sfc /scannow`?

Comment: I just restored the registry keys for DHCP service. I tried this with netbt but the whole service is not recognized as installed!

Comment: Did you see my question about `sfc /scannow`?